# Android Studio scaling of TextView

Tags: java, android, scaling

I'm working on an android maze app, but i fail at generating the maze. The free spaces should be ' ' and the walls of the maze should be '#'. The maze is always a square. My function to generate a random maze works if I use f.e. '1' for walls and '2' for the free spaces. I then cast the String[] ,in which my maze gets saved ,to a Textview and everything looks fine. If I work with the ' ' and '#' the shape gets messed up and it isn't a square. I append the strings in the array to the textview and append a '\n' to skip a line down to begin a new row. Here is an image of my solution: [image]

and here a picture how it should look:

[image]

I see that in the bottom picture the content of the textview uses all the space it got and scales, now i tried for the last 2 hours to scale my output but i cant get all the chars to use the maximum width of the textview to scale nicely. Can someone give me a hint?
The scaling should work with all sizes of mazes.
Here are my TextView settings :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/maze"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="426dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"/>
```

Comment: You need to use a mono-space font so ` ` and `#` take same width

Comment: Thank you soo much !! You saved my evening, I thought I'm going insane haha